# How to use docker_image and docker_container module in Ansible

Tags: docker, ansible

I would like to make a simple script that can deploy and download docker image from docker hub using Ansible but when I am trying to execute mycode I experience some errors as follows:

```
PLAY [manage docker using ansible] *********************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] *********************************************************
ok: [controller]
ok: [worker]

TASK [ping hosts] **************************************************************
ok: [controller]
ok: [worker]

TASK [pull docker image] *******************************************************
fatal: [controller]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (docker_image) module: source Supported parameters include: api_version,archive_path,buildargs,cacert_path,cert_path,container_limits,debug,docker_host,dockerfile,filter_logger,force,http_timeout,key_path,load_path,name,nocache,path,pull,push,repository,rm,ssl_version,state,tag,timeout,tls,tls_hostname,tls_verify,use_tls"}
fatal: [worker]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "msg": "Unsupported parameters for (docker_image) module: source Supported parameters include: api_version,archive_path,buildargs,cacert_path,cert_path,container_limits,debug,docker_host,dockerfile,filter_logger,force,http_timeout,key_path,load_path,name,nocache,path,pull,push,repository,rm,ssl_version,state,tag,timeout,tls,tls_hostname,tls_verify,use_tls"}
        to retry, use: --limit @/home/testuser/docker_manage.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
controller                 : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
worker                     : ok=2    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

here is my code:

```
---
 - name: manage docker using ansible
   hosts: all
   become: true
   tasks:
    - name: ping hosts
      ping:
    - name: pull docker image
      docker_image:
       name: busybox
       source: pull
    - name: deploy container
      docker_container:
       name: first_container
       image: busybox
       state: present
```

I have tried to follow guide on this [link] (https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/scenario_guides/guide_docker.html) to config my ansible.cfg file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Unsupported parameters for (docker_image) module: **source**

Although you did not provide your ansible version in your question, I'm quite sure you need to upgrade (or to remove this parameter). The `source` parameter was added in ansible 2.8

Ref: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/docker_image_module.html#parameter-source

Comment: Thank u for ur advice. finally, it works on my script